# Save a form from web for java in using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, repository

I am a newbie in java and trying to learn how to web application works.
Using spring boot in IntelliJ IDEA
Now I have no idea how to solve this problem on class.

the question is asking to save the form.

first the article calls the save method on controller

##### **`TodoController.java`**

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TodoController {
    ...

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String register(TodoForm todoForm) {
        todoService.saveTodo(todoForm);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

##### **`TodoService.java`**

```
@Service
...
public class TodoService {

    private final TodoRepository todoRepository;

    public List<Todo> searchAllTodo() {
        return todoRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void saveTodo(TodoForm todoForm) {
        todoRepository.save(Todo.of(todoForm));
    }
}
```

##### **`TodoForm.java`**

```
@Data
public class TodoForm {
    private String title;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate deadline;
}
```

and I have no idea how to use get method and return data from Todo.java on the "?" place.

##### **`Todo.java`**

```
public class Todo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private LocalDate deadline;
    private boolean status;

    ...

    public static ? of(TodoForm todoForm) {
       ?
    }
```

Thanks for your helping

Comment: Look at `TodoRepository` and see what type `save` takes, that answers your first `?`. Then look at `TodoForm` and think about how to make an instance of the type you want given the data in a `TodoForm`.

Comment: Do you mean this thing in TodoRepository? 
' Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.xxx.xxx.xxx.entity.Todo' '

Answer (score 0):

You probably would need to add in your controller argument
@RequestBody, so fields could be mapped

See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

To see test the results you could use Postman
(To test also add @ResponseBody to get the model back in Postman)